# Trigger angular material autocomplete after three letters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

I am trying to create an Angular Material Autocomplete that triggers after the user has typed in at least three letters. I get the data from an API call...

Currently I have it working like so that upon click in the input field it triggers the API call and it calls all the data which is really bad...

My ideal scenario and what I want to achieve would be that the API call triggers after the user has typed in at least three characters and only matching results are displayed in the mat-option element...

I hope I was clear enough with what I am trying to achieve, if not, let me know in a comment bellow...

Here is my code:
**dashboard.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="dasboardSearchForm" class="dashboardSearch">
  <div class="form-fields">
    <mat-form-field class="dashboard-search">
      <mat-label>Search users...</mat-label>
      <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" placeholder="search users..." [matAutocomplete]="auto" (change)="onSelected($event)">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" routerLink="/customers/customers/{{option.id}}">
          {{option.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

**dashboard.component.ts:**

```
  onSelected(event: any) {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      // debounceTime(500),
      startWith(''),
      switchMap(value => this._filter(value))
    );
    console.log('onSelected: ', this.filteredOptions);
  }

  displayFn(user: AutocompleteCustomers): string {
    return user && user.name ? user.name : '';
  }

  private _filter(value: string) {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.dashboardService.getCustomers().pipe(
      filter(data => !!data),
      map((data) => {
        debounceTime(3000);
        console.log(data);
        return data.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
      })
    )
  }
```

**dashboard.service.ts:**

```
  getCustomers(): Observable<AutocompleteCustomers[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<AutocompleteCustomers[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}data/customers`);
  }
```

here is also the Observable model:

```
export interface AutocompleteCustomers {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is the [RxJS `filter` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter).

```js
const filteredChanges = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  filter((value) => value.length >= 3)
);
```

There are, however, several other issues with your code.

1. The autocomplete will never be triggered because the changes observer is only set up after the user selects an option, which they can't do without autocomplete providing options to select. To fix this, move the `valueChanges` observer to class constructor or assign it directly to a class property.
2. `debounceTime` needs to be used in a pipe. With your current use, you are just creating an observable and not doing anything with it. It's also a bit strange to debounce the HTTP responses. Using debounce can be a good idea here, but you should use it on the input changes observable to reduce the number of requests to the backend, rather than ignoring responses.

Here's a rough idea of how it should work:

```js
class DashboardComponent {

  // ...

  public filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter((value) => value?.length > 3),
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap(value => this._filter(value))
  );

  private _filter(value: string) {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.dashboardService.getCustomers().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        if (!data) {
          return [];
        }
        return data.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
      })
    )
  }
}
```

It would probably be best to pass the query to the server and only return the customers that match the query. If you are going to search through the customers on the client side, it would be more efficient to just load the customers once and reuse the same list when searching.

```js
class DashboardComponent {

  // ...

  private customers = [];

  public filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter((value) => value?.length > 3),
    map((value) => {
      const query = value.toLowerCase(),
      return this.customers.filter(customer => customer.name.toLowerCase().includes(query))
    }),
  );

  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {
    this.dashboardService.getCustomers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.customers = data || [];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this... I have intended to filter on the server side (sending user input over params to backend) since the whole users list is more than 200k users

Comment: The second code you wrote work perfectly tho :)

Comment: No problem! Yeah, move it to the backend if you can. Modify the first version to remove `_filter()` and replace the `switchMap` with `switchMap(value => this.dashboardService.searchCustomers(value))` to make it work with server-side searching.

Comment: <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" routerLink="/customers/customers/{{option.id}}">
              {{option.name}}
            </mat-option>      should I also change something here?

Comment: since my results are not displayed but from console.log I can see that it works

Comment: My IDE is showing me this: Type HttpResponse<Object> | null is not assignable to type (HttpResponse<Object> & NgIterable<T>) | undefined | null

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the exact code. I believe that's because the HTTP request can return `null` sometimes, such as when there are network errors. You could 1) use RxJS `catchError` to return an empty array in those cases, or 2) subscribe in the component and assign to a `customers` array and use that in the view instead of the observable with the async pipe.